# Chrome's find text fails to highlight for a .pdf file

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions

I open a .pdf with Chrome and do ctrl-F but when it finds the text, it doesn't highlight it, so I can't find on a page with a ton of text.

Answer (score 0):

Super fast workaround/solution is to not use Chrome, but click and drag .pdf into Microsoft Word.  Boom!   10 seconds and Ctrl-F now works.

(No, I don't want to spend 30 precious minutes adding a Chrome extension and risk malware.)